# Pro COBOL support of Oracle Locator/Spatial Query

Tags: oracle11g, cobol, oracle-spatial, procobol

Does Pro COBOL 11g support the embedding of simple Oracle Locator Queries?

For example:

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX(b BLOCK_GROUP_IDX) */
  b.blockg_key, b.county_name, b.state_abbr, b.state_fips, b.county_fips
FROM block_group b
WHERE   
  SDO_RELATE(b.geom,MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307,
              MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(-100.319,39.911,NULL),NULL,NULL),
              'mask=CONTAINS querytype=WINDOW')='TRUE'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we did a proof-of-concept by writing a package and then we were able to call that package (from the mainframe via Pro*COBOL), with a lat/long, which performed the query and returned the result. Yeah!